# How to load specific row in table and then view controller based on a button press

Tags: ios

I swear I saw something about this in the documentation but can't find it (as I'm not sure what to look for).

Basically in my app, the first VC consists of a map where users can select annotations and a callout button on each one. Otherwise, the user can also select a button that'll open a searchable table of the buildings on the map and load view controllers displaying the details (basically  a master-detail setup).

What I want to do is for the callout to load a specified path for that particular building. So if I tap the callout on building A, it opens the detail view controller to show the information.

How do I do this, or what piece of documentation will help?

Comment: You'll need to further elaborate.

Comment: Sure. I've seen it in apps where you can drill down through tables to access the final detail controller, or you can press a shortcut button (or search) and it'll automatically skip the steps in between and show you the relevant detail controller.

Answer (score 0):

From reading this, it sounds like the map view an the table view belong to the same view controller. If so, then the view controller is where to want to centralize things. Again assuming the model is an array of data objects, have a method in the controller that does all the work of coordinating the different views.

```
- (void)selectModelAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index sender:(id)sender
{
    if (self.isSelectingModel)
        return;
    self.isSelectingModel = YES; // Stops recursive calls to -selectModelAtIndex:

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self indexPathForModelAtIndex:index];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone;
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNon animate:NO];

    MKAnnotation *annotation = [self annotationForModelAtIndex:index];
    [self.mapView selectAnnotation:av.annotation animated:NO];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Identifier Of Detail View" sender:sender];

    self.isSelectingModel = NO;
}
```

This is a single method which keeps the tableView and the mapView in sync before segueing to the details view controller. You need to have a `isSelectingModel` property, `-indexPathForModelAtIndex:`, and `-annotationForModelAtIndex:`.

This method is called by the table view and map view did select callbacks.